# Remove empty paragraphs from .docx using OpenXML SDK 2.0

Tags: vb.net, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to remove empty paragraphs from a .docx file before parsing the content into xml. How would I achieve this?

```
Protected Sub removeEmptyParagraphs(ByRef body As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Body)
    Dim colP As IEnumerable(Of Paragraph) = body.Descendants(Of Paragraph)()

    Dim count As Integer = colP.Count
    For Each p As Paragraph In colP
        If (p.InnerText.Trim() = String.Empty) Then
            body.RemoveChild(Of Paragraph)(p)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you might be running into is removing items from a list in a for each block. You could try using linq and the RemoveAll method:

```
Protected Sub removeEmptyParagraphs(ByRef body As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Body)
    Dim colP As IEnumerable(Of Paragraph) = body.Descendants(Of Paragraph)()
    colP.RemoveAll(Function(para) para.InnerText.Trim() = String.Empty)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help removing blank space for paragraph and even for blank pages too.

```
IEnumerable<Paragraph> paragraphs =       
                     myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>();

            foreach (Paragraph paragraph in paragraphs)
            {
                if (paragraph != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(paragraph.InnerText))
                {
                    paragraph.ParagraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties(
                                      new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "No Spacing" },
                                      new SpacingBetweenLines() { After = "0" }
                                      );
                    paragraph.ParagraphProperties.SpacingBetweenLines.AfterLines = 0;
                    paragraph.ParagraphProperties.SpacingBetweenLines.BeforeLines = 0;
                    paragraph.ParagraphProperties.SpacingBetweenLines.Line = "0";

                }
            }
```

Comment: Editing your answer to include a VB.NET version could be useful, especially as the question is tagged with VB.NET.